# HTML before JSON when using POST

Tags: azure, django-rest-framework

I have implemented something similar to the tutorial from [the Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views), with respect to this portion:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        #This line is not in the tutorial
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, headers=headers, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now, it works well on my computer (I get an HTTP 201, the location of the resource is in the header, the body is valid JSON), both with debug=True or debug=False, but when I upload it on my production server running Windows Azure, this is the response I get:

```
<head>
    <title>Document Moved</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found 
    <a HREF="location_from_http_header">here</a>
</body>{the json I'm supposed to get}
```

along with the same valid headers. Production is obviously with debug=False, my post request contains a header with Accept: application/json though the content-type of the response is "text/html; charset=UTF-8".

Any idea where this could come from?

Comment: Is this Azure Web Sites or you are hosting this on an Azure VM?

Comment: Might be related to: http://forums.iis.net/p/1209573/2073536.aspx?IIS+7+5+adding+Document+Moved+content+when+Location+header+is+present but has not being solved... Anyway try the first answer, hope it will help you :)

Comment: It's on Azure Web Sites, but Azure Web Sites runs on Windows Server VMs. It does seem to be the IIS + FastCGI that are messing with the content, see also: http://forums.iis.net/t/1158431.aspx. @MaximeLorant: I think the guy's response makes sense, you don't want to replace the content of the Location header.
The only fix that I could find is to replace the name "Location" in the header by something else, for example "Custom-location". That messes up the header syntax but at least your content is right...